# QWizardPage: how to re-disable "Next" button

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qwizard, qwizardpage

I have a `QWizardPage` where user is supposed to go through certain steps, at the end of which there is a button "Test". If user presses that button, two things happen:

1. "Next" button gets enabled in order to go to the next page of the `QWizard`. This is achieved by emitting a button's special signal which is connected to `QWizardPage`:

   `this->registerField("test*", m_button, "text", SIGNAL(testDone()));`

`m_button` is derived from `QPushButton` with a custom signal `testDone()`.

2. Button name is changed to "Try again" in order to offer an option to try the series of steps all over again. If user presses the button, the GUI elements return to the initial state (*except disabling the button "Next" on `QWizard`*).

**The question is:** for the second scenario, how do I make sure the "Next" button gets disabled after being enabled by the emitted `testDone()` signal?

I thought if I disconnect the particular signal `testDone()` from `QwizardPage` (after it is emitted), it would give the desired results, however, it did not work. I tried to disconnect everything on the `QWizardPage` (e.g. `this->disconnect`), but that also didn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control the pages "readyness", you typically override [`QWizardPage::isComplete`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html#isComplete) and signal changes via [`QWizardPage::completeChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizardpage.html#completeChanged).

So for your example, you could give your button a property and connect it accordingly:

```
class MyButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(bool ready READ isReady NOTIFY readyChanged)

public:
    MyButton(QWidget *parent);
    bool isReady() const;

signals:
    void readyChanged();
};
```

Whenever the button is pressed or the tests completed, emit the signal, and return the desired button state from the isReady function.

In your wizard page, override `isComplete` as:

```
bool isComplete() const {
    return QWizardPage::isComplete() && myButton->isReady();
}
```

and connect the signals in your page:

```
connect(myButton, &MyButton::readyChanged, this, &MyPage::completeChanged);
```

Comment: that works, thanks! It was also useful to know how to use Q_PROPERTY within this context.